# notepad++ how to index files to search faster?

Tags: search, notepad++

i was wondering if Notepad++ has a plugin or something to index the files so that the search will happen faster.

I have a very large project and i am waiting 10 min for one search in code base.

Any idea what might help me?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NPP has its limitations.. If you are looking at content indexing, look at [Copernic Search](http://www.copernic.com/) and [Google Desktop](http://desktop.google.com/)
They'll give you the best speeds!

Answer (score 0):

I use Sublime Text 2 to search through 4000 or more files with many directories. I searches through all of them in less than 10 seconds and shows the results as it finds them. I really like Sublime for searching. It uses python to do this. It comes with the program. You can also search in multiple file paths using commas between paths to search and also you can use regex in the search. It is free to try but will cost $60 if you like the program enough and I recommend it. It works in all 3 major OS's.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio's Entrian plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EntrianSolutions-RichieHindle.EntrianSourceSearchAfulltextindexsearchengineforyo) is a powerful tool to do indexed search within a Visual Studio Project